# SUM + CONVERT DATATIME VACHAR

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need `SUM` the results of `CONVERT`. At the moment I have the following, anybody know how to sum the result for name or chapa?

```
SELECT 
    PFUNC.CHAPA, PFUNC.NOME,
    CONVERT (varchar(6), DATEDIFF(second, AABONOFUNCIONARIO.DATAHORAINICIO, AABONOFUNCIONARIO.DATAHORAFIM) / 3600) + ':' + 
        RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), (DATEDIFF(second, AABONOFUNCIONARIO.DATAHORAINICIO, AABONOFUNCIONARIO.DATAHORAFIM) % 3600) / 60), 2) + ':' + 
        RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), DATEDIFF(second, AABONOFUNCIONARIO.DATAHORAINICIO, AABONOFUNCIONARIO.DATAHORAFIM) % 60), 2) AS Abonos
FROM
    PFUNC(NOLOCK), AABONOFUNCIONARIO(NOLOCK)
```

Result

```
CHAPA    | NOME                             |  Abonos
---------+----------------------------------+----------
00000635 | ALESSANDRO MAIA DE SOUZA         | 0:12:00
00000635 | ALESSANDRO MAIA DE SOUZA         | 0:30:00
00000585 | ANDRELANE DE JESUS SOUSA SALES   | 0:52:00
00000585 | ANDRELANE DE JESUS SOUSA SALES   | 0:46:00
```

I need `SUM(Abonos)`.

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock hints](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: Also don't use antiquated comma separated join style, use 'modern' `join..on` syntax. In your case `cross join`, is that what you really want?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are actually trying to convert into hours, minutes and seconds and *then* sum up the time?

Leaving aside all the bad smells in this script and focussing on the question at hand, you can just sum up the time differences and *then* convert into your desired format:

```
with t as
(
    select pf.CHAPA
          ,pf.NOME
          ,sum(datediff(second,af.DATAHORAINICIO,af.DATAHORAFIM)) as Abonos
    from PFUNC(NOLOCK) as pf
        cross join AABONOFUNCIONARIO(NOLOCK) as af
    group by pf.CHAPA
            ,pf.NOME
)
select CHAPA
      ,NOME
      ,case when Abonos >= 86400  -- Handle any instances greater than 24 hours
            then convert(varchar(5), Abonos / 86400) + '.'
            else ''
            end                   -- Then return a normal HH:mm:ss time format
        + convert(varchar(8), dateadd(second, Abonos, 0), 108)
       as Abonos
from t;
```

Comment: my intention is to obtain this result.

CHAPA    | NOME                             |  Abonos
---------+----------------------------------+----------
00000635 | ALESSANDRO MAIA DE SOUZA         | 0:42:00


instead of this

CHAPA    | NOME                             |  Abonos
---------+----------------------------------+----------
00000635 | ALESSANDRO MAIA DE SOUZA         | 0:12:00
00000635 | ALESSANDRO MAIA DE SOUZA         | 0:30:00

Comment: @Tiago  I am fairly sure based on the limited information you have provided that is why my query here does.  Can you please test the query and share both the output it produces and where it isn't returning what you require?

Comment: @Tiago please edit your question to include the expected output. It's really not readable in a comment.

Comment: @iamdave thanks
I'm sorry for the little information I provided.

The return I got was this.
chapa  | NOME    |Abonos   
00003285 | ALESSANDRO MAIA DE SOUZA |5340.21:07:00

The field I am trying to sum the differences to has this format:

2019-03-12 13:40:00.0000000

Comment: @Tiago It looks like you need to add additional filtering on your query both in the `where` and the `join`, which we can't help you with here because we can't see your database.  The value you are seeing of `5340.21:07:00` means 5340 days. 21 hours, 07 minutes and 00 seconds, which will be the sum total of all the values resulting from `cross join` as defined in your question (from table1, table2 is a cross join).  You likely need to edit your join to something like `from PFUNC(NOLOCK) as pf join AABONOFUNCIONARIO(NOLOCK) as af on pf.JoinColumnName = af.JoinColumnName`